# How can I use a third party component in Reactjs NET

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc

Good morning,
first of all, let me say that I'm very noob to the world of react so please be kind.
What I want to do is simple: use a third party component into my web app, but since I cannot use import statement in Reactjs net I don't know how to import the component. I've installed already this component via npm, but now I'm stuck. Can you help me please?

Comment: "but since I cannot use import statement" - Why is this, what have you tried? It should work, it is the basis of all React (and Nodejs) programming. Please give a relevant code sample.

Comment: I'm using reactjs net for my web app mvc and there I cannot import/export components like normally one should (in fact, with your answers probably you would automatically help me to learn how to import my own components from other jsx files in this case).

Comment: did you find out how to make it work?